# What is the syntax for xargs' -I flag argument?

Tags: linux, shell, xargs

The documentation only states vaguely what it does in words, and I can't find any examples readily on the internet.

So, how can I use the -I flag of xargs? I know it has something to do with string substitution in the argument command, but its not clear how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `tldr xargs`:

```
- Execute the command once for each input line, replacing any occurrences of the placeholder (here marked as `_`) with the input line:

    arguments_source | xargs -I _ command _ optional_extra_arguments
```

so, something like this:

```
$ echo "foo" | xargs -I _ echo "bar-"_
bar-foo
```

`xargs` takes the input `foo`, replaces the `_` with it and instead of printing `bar-_` prints `bar-foo` to console